# Unable to find Cocoapod MotionKit framework Derived Data

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift2, core-motion

I installed the library with Pod. But I got the following error when I build the app:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: 
can't open file: \
    /Users/taiyuanz/Library/Developer \
    /Xcode/DerivedData/RollingBall-gbmnblxxirswheemtfgncxsqywkj/Build/\
    Products/Debug-iphoneos/Ballman.app/Frameworks/MotionKit 
      (No such file or directory)
```

This happens after I upgraded the Xcode. How to fix such error?

Comment: did you try to clean derived data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode > Window > Projects > [project] > Delete

[image: Delete Derived Data]